# Woocommerce checkout fields logged in vs guest user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a piece of code in my functions.php file to customise the checkout fields, as below.

```
add_filter(  'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    ## ---- 1.  Sort billing email and phone fields ---- ##

    $fields['billing_address_2']['priority'] = 60;
    $fields['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 70;
    $fields['billing_suburb']['priority'] = 80;
    $fields['billing_city']['priority'] = 90;
    $fields['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 100;
    $fields['billing_state']['priority'] = 110;
    $fields['billing_country']['priority'] = 120;

    $fields['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'e.g. name@domain.co.za';
    $fields['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'e.g. John';
    $fields['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'e.g. Smith';
    $fields['billing_address_google']['placeholder'] = 'Enter your billing address';
    $fields['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = 'Apartment, suite, unit etc. (Optional)';
    $fields['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = '';
```

You'll notice the placeholder for billing_address_1 is blank, which is how we want it.

The problem is, this only works if someone is logged into their account and using the checkout. If someone is not logged in and checking out as a guest, the placeholder says "House number and street name". I have inspected the code and it does indeed say this. (screenshot attached).

I cannot find where the code is that tells it to do this - or why the code I have doesn't override it.

Does anyone know why would it be different when a user is logged in or not or how I could find the code with this placeholder?

The website is flowersforeveryone.co.za

Thanks!!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can do using following filter.

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_billing_checkout_fields', 20, 1 );
    function override_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

        ## ---- 1.  Sort billing email and phone fields ---- ##

        $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['priority'] = 60;
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 70;
        $fields['billing']['billing_suburb']['priority'] = 80;
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['priority'] = 90;
        $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 100;
        $fields['billing']['billing_state']['priority'] = 110;
        $fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 120;

        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'e.g. name@domain.co.za';
        $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'e.g. John';
        $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'e.g. Smith';
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_google']['placeholder'] = 'Enter your billing address';
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = 'Apartment, suite, unit etc. (Optional)';
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = '';

        return $fields;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try it and let you know how I go!

Comment: This hasn't seem to have made a difference. It doesn't affect the placeholder that's there